# Is it possible to add footnotes to Flextable cells and have the footnote text appear at the bottom of word docx page?

Tags: r, flextable

I have been using Flextables in accompaniment with RMarkdown to generate word documents from data. So far it has been great. However, I have not been able to do one thing. I cannot generate footnotes for cells in my Flextables and have the text of the footnotes show up at the bottom of the page with my other footnotes that I create through plain RMarkdown text.

Unfortunately, the footnote() function from Flextable only generates footnotes in the bottom cells of my Flextable. I have tried using append_chunk() to my cell with various 'value' types (as_word_field, etc). I have tried using ftExtra() and making the cells RMarkdown content with colformat_md(). I have also tried wrapping the 'suffix' parameter in colformat_char() inside cat() and knit_print() without success.

Here is an example of what I would like:

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | row_one |
| Second | row_two<sup>1</sup> |

<sup>1</sup> Sample Footnote Text (located at the bottom of word document)

Also, I cannot just add blank table rows till my table reaches the bottom of the document and put footer there because sometimes my tables overflow beyond a single page. However, I need the footnotes to appear at the bottom of the page on which they appear in the table.

Happy to clarify anything or provide more details if needed. Thank you kindly.

Comment: (note I am the maintainer of the package) No it is not possible with flextable.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your response. Is there some place I should make a feature request, David? No worry if you don't think this is worth implementing or if it isn't possible to do so.

Comment: In flextable github repo. It can work with officer, but the resulting code would be a packet of noodle with code in officer and code in flextable. I think it can not work with quarto, I am not sure if it can work with rmarkdown